# Cypher Query does not work

Tags: cypher

I represent SMS text messages sent by persons. In order to simplify the problem I have only 2 nodes (one Person, one Phone) and 3 relationship (the person has a phone and  sent to himself two text messages). The graph was created as follows:

```
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
Node aNode1 = graphDb.createNode();
aNode1.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label("Person"));
aNode1.setProperty("Name", "Juana");
tx.success();

Node aNode2 = graphDb.createNode();
aNode2.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label("Phone"));
aNode2.setProperty("Number", "1111-1111");
tx.success();

// (:Person) -[:has]->(:Phone)
aNode1.createRelationshipTo(aNode2, RelationshipType.withName("has"));
tx.success();


// finally SMS text sent at different moments
// (:Phone) -[:sms]-> (:Phone)
Relationship rel1 = aNode2.createRelationshipTo(aNode2, RelationshipType.withName("sms"));
rel1.setProperty("Length", 100);
tx.success();

Relationship rel2 = aNode2.createRelationshipTo(aNode2, RelationshipType.withName("sms"));
rel2.setProperty("Length", 50);
tx.success();

}
```

When I execute the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH  (p1 :Person)-[:has]-> (n1 :Phone) -[r :sms]-(n2: Phone)<-[:has]-(p2 :Person)
RETURN p1, p2
```

I obtain zero tuples. I do not understand the resultset because I have to sms text between p1 and p2 (in this case the same person).

Surprisingly, if I eliminates the node p2 in the query:

```
MATCH  (p1 :Person)-[:has]-> (n1 :Phone) -[r :sms]-(n2: Phone)
RETURN p1
```

I obtain Juana, as expected.

I can not understand the resultset (zero tuples) of my first query.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher will only traverse a particular relationship once when trying to traverse a path, to avoid infinite loops. You already traverse the `(p1:Person) - [:HAS] - > (n1:Phone)` relationship once in your query, so you can't get back to Juana from her phone. This doesn't apply to nodes, however, which is why you can get her phone twice from the looped `[:sms]` relationship.